# openvpn route ALL traffic through VPN but through particular client (not server)

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

I have managed to setup a configuration where specific routes are routed through a particular client . For example I setup route X.X.X.0 255.255.255.0 and in the client A iroute X.X.X.0 255.255.255.0 , so all the traffic from client Y towards X.X.X.0 is going through the VPN and then through client A to the network. This works normally.

However How can I setup all the clients except client A to route their traffic through client A? If I set redirect-gateway def1 , then the traffic is routed through the vpn server itself. This not what I want, I want instead of having to specify special iroutes in client A, having ALL the traffic pass through client A.

According to my understanding I tried iroute 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 in client A and correspondingly push route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 in the server so all the vpn traffic go through client A , but it did not work?

Is it possible? I think yes, in this case what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly possible and even at this very moment I'm connected using such setup. My VPN server is in Germany and exit node in US. I cannot test the setup below right now (mine is done a little different way, so it's not enough to copy/paste), but it should theoretically be enough.

Your task can simply be achieved by pushing default routes to "all minus one" of your clients using **client config dir** feature (check `--ccd` option in OpenVPN manual). In client's ccd file you need to add lines similar to these:

```
push "route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 EXIT_IP"
push "route vpn_gateway 255.255.255.255 net_gateway"
```

Replace EXIT_IP with your exit node's IP address in VPN tunnel (not a public one).

Don't change `vpn_gateway` and `net_gateway`, they will be substituted automatically with OpenVPN. This line is to add a direct route to VPN server over your pre-existing net gateway to prevent routing loop.